Weak convergence in $L^p$ preserves $L^\infty$-norm
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^N$ be open. I thought about a generalization of another question, leading me to this:
Assume $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ for some $p \in [1, \infty)$ (i.e. weak convergence) and $C := \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lVert f_n \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} < \infty$. I want to know if $\lVert f \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C$.
To answer this question I first recognized that for $\varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$:
$$
\int_{\Omega} f\varphi = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n \varphi \leq C \int_{\Omega}\lvert \varphi \rvert
$$
So $F:\big(C_0^\infty(\Omega), \lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^1(\Omega)} \big) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(\varphi) := \int_{\Omega} f \varphi$ is a continuous operator. By density, we can extend it to a continuous operator $\hat{F} \in L^1(\Omega)'$, i.e. there is some $\hat{g}\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\lVert \hat{g} \rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C$ and $\hat{F}(h) = \int_{\Omega} h \hat{g}$ for all $h \in L^1(\Omega)$. Then,
$$
\int_{\Omega} f\varphi = \int_{\Omega} \hat{g}\varphi \quad \quad \forall \varphi \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)
$$
and thus $f = \hat{g}$ by the fundamental lemma of calc. of variations. Hence the claim.
Can anyone comment on whether this is correct or if there is an easy argument that I missed? I am not sure whether the extension argument is correct and whether I messed up some of the spaces.

Ι don't see anything wrong with your solution. Note that you do not need density of $C_0^\infty$ to extend $F$, you can invoke Hahn Banach
